# Why is my React app not loading app shell instantly?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, service-worker, progressive-enhancement, progressive-web-apps

[image: My app Network timeline at page reload] As shown on the screen capture below: On page reload my webapp's required resources are fetched from service worker, but it still takes 1.42 for anything to render on the page. What i was expecting, on all reloads of the page the items cached by the service worker should render instantly. 
Is it something I'm missing?

Comment: Just a wild guess: try the [timeline profiling](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool?hl=en).

Comment: @wOxxOm I looked at that, seems to be evaluating the vendor script for my app the longest. And then parsing html and my app.js script. IS is possible to stop browser to not fetch the vendor script or the app script if it hasn't changed ?

Comment: my service worker script does run first before vendor.js and app.js so I can check if my cached resources have changed(using hashes) ?

Answer (score 0):

The files may not be cached and the installation of the Service Worker failed.

Its possible that there are files that failed to be downloaded, so it won't be considered as installed. As discussed on the [Install a Service Worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-worker/install?hl=en) page, having a long list of files can increase the chances of a caching failure, leading to the service worker not getting installed.

Comment: From the screenshot it shows status 200 from Service Worker.